# Embedded Timed Text for closed-captioning? Is that possible?

Tags: subtitles

I am going to be working on a video project that needs closed captioning. The requirement we got from the client says....

**Closed Captioning**

- Embedded Timed Text subtitle track (ISO/IEC 14496-17)

After doing some research I haven't been able to find anything that would let you embed a Timed Text file into a video. Is that even possible? What would be the process for accomplishing this? I am using Adobe Premiere.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_17
"Timed Text" Format comes in many flavors

example tools would be ffmpeg, subler, mp4box

Answer (score 1):

If you can use mkv instead of mp4 as your container format, there is widespread player and muxer support for various subtitle formats in [matroska](http://www.matroska.org/).  (widespread throughout free / open source software.  I can't comment on other players.)

Then you can use SRT, ASS, and many other text subtitle formats.  You can even use bitmap sub formats like VOBSUB (dvd) or PGS (blu-ray).

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitle_%28captioning%29#For_software_video_players) has an interesting table of subtitle formats.

To properly answer your question, though, I just tried muxing SRT subs into an mp4.  It doesn't work.

`ffmpeg -i in.mkv -i in.srt -c copy /var/tmp/out.mkv`  # works
`ffmpeg -i in.mkv -i in.srt -c copy /var/tmp/out.mp4`  # just timestamps

The mp4 has a `mov_text` stream, but displaying it in [mpv](http://mpv.io/) just shows "00:00:00.000" or some other timestamp, with no text.  Ok, apparently ffmpeg doesn't get it right unless you specifically use `-c:s mov_text`.  If you use `-map 0 -map 1`, I get

```
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:2 (subrip (srt) -> ? (?))
Encoder (codec none) not found for output stream #0:2
```

(My subs are in a separate file, not muxed in the mkv, so I need a -map for each to make sure I take all streams from all files.  Otherwise ffmpeg just takes the first a, v, and sub stream it finds.  And without `-map 1`, it doesn't try to use the srt input at all, for some reason.  Like I said, it makes a mov_text stream, though.)

Anyway, I left in my mis-steps in case they're helpful when you're trying to figure out this stuff yourself.  This works and plays with subs in mpv:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -i in.srt -codec copy -c:s mov_text /var/tmp/out.mp4
```

The key line in the output is:

```
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:2 (subrip (srt) -> mov_text (native))
```

For editting your subtitles, you can use anything that can produce a subtitle format that ffmpeg can read.  (It should be able to convert any text-based format to mov_text.)  [Subtitle Edit](http://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit/) is one of the newer better-maintained GUIs, and runs on Windows and Linux at least.  IDK about OS X.